# Is this JSON file correctly formatted?

Tags: json

I am very new to JSON and was wondering if this is considered proper.

My intent is to pre-create some colors and attach them to one (or more) theme(s). Perhaps some themes may have other colors that, for whatever reason, have not been pre-defined. Ultimately, I will take themes and apply them to other objects in similar fashion as the colors (by name)...

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "colors": [
    { "name": "RED", "color": { "red": 255, "green": 0, "blue": 0 } },
    { "name": "BLUE", "color": { "red": 0, "green": 0, "blue": 255 } },
    { "name": "GREEN", "color": { "red": 0, "green": 255, "blue": 0 } },
    { "name": "MAGENTA", "color": { "red": 255, "green": 0, "blue": 255 } },
    { "name": "WHITE", "color": { "red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 255 } },
    { "name": "YELLOW", "color": { "red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 0 } }
  ],
  "themes": [
      { 
        "name": "Patriotic", 
        "colors": [ "RED", "WHITE", "BLUE" ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Valentine's Day",
        "colors": [
          { "red": 255, "green": 0, "blue": 100 },
          { "red": 255, "green": 255, "blue": 255 }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "St. Patrick's Day",
        "colors": [ "GREEN", "WHITE" ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Halloween",
        "colors": [
          "YELLOW",
          { "red": 201, "green": 90, "blue": 110 },
          { "red": 92, "green": 0, "blue": 200 }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Is this considered proper format? Acceptable? If not, what would a better approach be?

I should say that this is for a personal IOT project which has very limited memory for configuration storage (which this will be a configuration file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this considered proper format?

What you show is a well formed JSON document.  Whether it contains sensible values is difficult to say without knowing whatever the requirements are, but just from a perspective of being valid JSON, I think that is.

Comment: So then, referring to "YELLOW" in the "Halloween" theme as a foreign-key to yellow's  definition will be parsed with a JSON library. But will the data be automatically substituted or do I have to perform the substitutions myself? Is there a way to utilize a foreign-key type look-up native to a typical JSON parser? Or is that entirely on me to handle in my program?

Comment: "Or is that entirely on me to handle in my program?" - It isn't exactly clear what it is that needs to be done, but whatever that is, is going to happen in some program.  JSON isn't a piece of software or a system that does something.  JSON is a notation.  The document that you show in the question is valid JSON.  JSON doesn't really "do" anything through.  JSON is just a document format.